# Limit(n) vs Show(n) performance disparity in Pyspark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Trying to get a deeper understanding of how spark works and was playing around with the pyspark cli (2.4.0). I was looking for the difference between using `limit(n).show()` and `show(n)`. I ended up getting two very different performance times for two very similar queries. Below are the commands I ran. The parquet file referenced in the code below has about 50 columns and is over 50gb in size on remote HDFS.

```
# Create dataframe
>>> df = sqlContext.read.parquet('hdfs://hdfs.host/path/to.parquet') ↵

# Create test1 dataframe
>>> test1 = df.select('test_col') ↵
>>> test1.schema ↵
StructType(List(StructField(test_col,ArrayType(LongType,true),true)))
>>> test1.explain() ↵
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [test_col#40]
+- *(1) FileScan parquet [test_col#40]
    Batched: false,
    Format: Parquet,
    Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://hdfs.host/path/to.parquet],
    PartitionCount: 25,
    PartitionFilters: [],
    PushedFilters: [],
    ReadSchema: struct<test_col:array<bigint>>

# Create test2 dataframe
>>> test2 = df.select('test_col').limit(5) ↵
>>> test2.schema ↵
StructType(List(StructField(test_col,ArrayType(LongType,true),true)))
>>> test2.explain() ↵
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 5
+- *(1) Project [test_col#40]
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [test_col#40]
     Batched: false,
     Format: Parquet,
     Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://hdfs.host/path/to.parquet],
     PartitionCount: 25,
     PartitionFilters: [],
     PushedFilters: [],
     ReadSchema: struct<test_col:array<bigint>>
```

Notice that the physical plan is almost identical for both `test1` and `test2`. The only exception is test2's plan starts with "CollectLimit 5". After setting this up I ran `test1.show(5)` and `test2.show(5)`. Test 1 returned the results instantaneously. Test 2 showed a progress bar with 2010 tasks and took about 20 minutes to complete (I only had one executor)

Question
Why did test 2 (with limit) perform so poorly compared to test 1 (without limit)? The data set and result set were identical and the physical plan was nearly identical.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind:

- `show()` is an alias for `show(20)` and relies internally on `take(n: Int): Array[T]`
- `limit(n: Int)` returns another dataset and is an expensive operation that reads the whole source

Answer (score 0):

Limit - result in new dataframe and taking longer time because this is because predicate pushdown is currently not supported in your input file format. Hence reading entire dataset and applying limit.

Comment: Got it, so does that mean the two tests would have more similar performance if reading from like MySQL instead of HDFS?